# auto-mount not working on HDD

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd, automount

According to *Disks* my external HDD is set to automatic mount, but when I boot it isn't mounted. I need to pull out the USB cable and put it back in for it to start working. Is there a way for the HDD to be detected and mounted at boot?

Answer (score 1):

ok let's do this instead open the disk utility, now, turn the slide to off, select mount on startup or boot.
Now you have to add a line before the " x-gvfs-show " add " comment=" so it should be like this " comment=x-gvfs-show".

Now i selected the mount point /media/yourusername/Linux.

After that input your password and reboot.

Take a look to the image below.

[image]

Comment: Actually it didn't work after all. When I booted today it said "partition not found. Press S to skip" or something like that. The computer just doesn't recognize the usb device is there at startup and I have to un- and replug it. I feel like it's related to the HDD though, as it doesn't have this problem with other HDD's I think...

Comment: Did you mounted under /media/yourusername/dskxxx?Some people prefer to mount under /mnt/, i personaly dont.

Comment: yes under /media/user/ where ubuntu always mounts my devices.